# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I've searched for this error and I came up with this:

"I should surround the username and password in my code with single quotes" ... I did but the code still shows the same exact error!

Here is my code after being fixed:

```
String strng = " SELECT * FROM Table "
        + " WHERE Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND " 
        + " Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
```

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: FOR THE LOVE OF GOD USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES!

Comment: `Table` would need to be `[Table]`. Use parameterised queries (and more descriptive table names. Such as `User`)

Comment: what is the name of the table you are trying to query? is it actually *Table* ?

Comment: This looks like it should run fine. You're not actually using Table as the name of the table are you? Open up SSMS and toy around with your query to get it working yourself if you continue to have problems.

Comment: @MikeC. From the error in the title it seems they are.

Comment: @MartinSmith what are the parameterized queries .. I'm new to this & that's how we studies it in college!

Comment: @SaraKholusi - Using parameters protects you from SQL injection. At the moment your string concatenation approach allows end users to execute arbitrary commands against your database.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `Table` is the real name of your table try this

```
String strng = " SELECT * FROM [Table] "
    + " WHERE Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND " 
    + " Password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
```

Notice the `[]` around `Table`, this is for escaping purposes since `Table` is a reserved word.

I agree with existing comments that this is not a correct approach for building a sql query. You're exposed to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack and from readability point of view is also worse. You should use parameters instead.

```
String strng = @" 
    SELECT * FROM [Table]
    WHERE Username = @UserName AND
    Password = @Password";
...
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUsername.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
```

Two more things you have to take into account:

- Escape user input to avoid [XSS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)
- Store encrypted passwords on database and not plain text

Comment: Or he could use a stored procedure and acces it in c# using Exec spName.